# Removing newer linux kernel and retain the older one

Tags: kernel

I updated the linux kernel from 3.5 to 3.16 by downloading tar.xz file from linuxkernel.org and compiled, and subsequently installed successfully on my ubuntu machine(meaning I am able to see the boot options  when I start the pc and can log into either 3.5 or 3.16 version of linux kernel)
but now I want to remove the newer version. steps I followed

1. logged into older version 3.5
2. ran `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`
   but there is no mention of 3.16

   > ```
   > root@h2o-Vostro-1015:~# dpkg --list | grep linux-image
   > ii  linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic              3.5.0-17.28                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
   > ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic        3.5.0-17.28                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
   > ii  linux-image-generic                       3.5.0.17.19                               i386         Generic Linux kernel image
   > ```

which indicated that I have only 3.5 version installed,but I can boot into 3.16 version and also

- I checked the /boot directory, there I can see the initrd.img-3.16.0-rc4, which proves that the 3.16 version is still present.

had above steps worked I would have tried either 
removal through synaptic or

> `sudo apt-get remove --purge 3.16.0*`

command via terminal.

kindly advise how can I remove the newer version.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Comment: the solution in given link to question is for removing older versions of linux kernel, whereas I am intersted in removing the newer version. in addition to that I tried the ones given in this answer too but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you installed the kernel manually, posting a link to what instructions you followed would be helpful.

To delete manually, you can run  *ls -l /boot*  . Typically the files would be:

1. abi-*
2. initrd.img-*
3. config-*
4. System.map-*
5. vmlinuz-*

Delete these files (corresponding to 3.16) and update grub.

Answer (score 0):

All your kernels should be found in /boot. As super user(root), delete the ones you don't need and update grub.

Comment: are you suggesting manual removal of files & directory..? and if yes which ones..?

Comment: Yes. "Which ones?" The ones you specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Installing kernels (or other types of software) OUTSIDE of the package manager causes your work not to show up in apt-get (dpkg) and may have some ramifications to system stability and maintainability.

It is easy to remove a specific kernel however, simply go to the /boot file, and remove the files with the matching version number.  Then you must update the grub menu to remove that entry (if it even exists) in it.